# Octave Calculus with matrix

Tags: octave

i'm developing a program in octave that i will explain as i put the code.
So i have this matrix in a file called matprec.m:

```
function [res1] = obtemDadosPrec()
   res1 = [
1,2001,1,2,0.00;
1,2001,1,5,5.33;
2,2001,1,5,4.57;
3,2001,1,5,5.33;
4,2001,1,5,5.59;
5,2001,1,5,4.32;
2,2001,1,13,0.00;
3,2001,1,13,0.00;
4,2001,1,13,0.00;
3,2001,1,30,30.73;
2,2001,2,1,1.02;
3,2001,2,1,1.52;
4,2001,2,1,1.78;
5,2001,2,1,1.27;
1,2001,2,2,1.78;
2,2001,2,2,1.27;
3,2001,2,2,1.78;
4,2001,2,2,2.03;
5,2001,2,2,1.78;
1,2001,3,4,18.03;
3,2001,3,4,15.75;
5,2001,3,4,17.53;
1,2001,3,5,13.46;
2,2001,3,5,12.19;
3,2001,3,5,11.94;
4,2001,3,5,9.65;
5,2001,3,5,10.92;
2,2001,4,30,0.00;
4,2001,4,30,0.00];
format short g
return
endfunction
```

so in this matrix the first column is just the station where we measure the amount of precipitation, the second is the year, the third is the month, the fourth is the day and the fifth is the value of precipitation.
And what i want to do in another file is call this matrix and do the following calculus, in the month 1 i want do the average on all the days for example:

in month 1 day 5 i have 5 values 5.33, 4.57, 5.33, 5.59, 4.32, so i would do

(5.33 + 4.57 + 5.33 + 5.59 + 4.32)/5 = 5.028

And i want to do that for all the days and when i have all the days i would add them all to know the amount of precipitation in that month, and do that for all the 4 months.

I'm kind of stuck there if you could help me i would appreciate, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First, get your array

```
>> Result        = obtemDadosPrec();
```

Then get a logical array where rows corresponding to month == 1 are true (i.e. 1) and all others are false (i.e. 0)

```
>> month1Indices = Result(:,3) == 1;
```

Use this logical array to perform [logical indexing](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) and isolate only the 'true' rows.

```
>> month1Rows    = Result(month1Indices, :);
```

Repeat same procedure to isolate 'day 5'

```
>> day5Indices   = month1Rows(:,4) == 5;
>> day5Rows      = month1Rows(day5Indices , :);
```

Calculate the average of the 5th column.

```
>> mean(day5Rows(:,5))
ans = 5.028
```

Comment: i tried that but i always get the error:  **error: 'obtemDadosPrec' undefined near line 1 column 17
error: called from
    grafico3 at line 1 column 15**   The code i input was:                                                                      _Result = obtemDadosPrec();
month1Indices = Result(:,3) == 1;
month1Rows    = Result(month1Indices, :);
day5Indices   = month1Rows(:,4) == 5;
day5Rows      = month1Rows(day5Indices , :);
mean(day5Rows(:,5))
ans = 5.028_   And sorry for the delay i was busy, Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed you said the file is called `matprec.m`. The filename and the name of the function must match. Either call your file `obtemDadosPrec.m` or call your function `matprec` instead.

Comment: (also, ensure that the file is "in your path", which in the simplest of cases means "in the current directory").

Comment: Thanks it's almost done, so it's everything working nicely but i have to add a lot of code to go trough all the days in a month, so i decided to create a while loop and plot him like this: **while (a < 30 && b < 4)
Result        = matprec();
month1Indices = Result(:,3) == a;
month1Rows    = Result(month1Indices, :);
day5Indices   = month1Rows(:,4) == b;
day5Rows      = month1Rows(day5Indices , :);
  mean(day5Rows(:,5))
  x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
  plot(x,mean(day5Rows(:,5)));
  endwhile** but nothing happens when i run it, why?

Comment: @HStylerMiranda I know it's tempting to get it all sorted in a single post, but it is generally discouraged to ask new unrelated questions in the same thread, since the answer tends to deviate from the original context making it difficult for people to find it. Not to mention "holding my answer hostage until I help further" is bad form after I put effort into answering it. What you're asking here is a separate question. Please post this separately with a clear minimal example of what you're asking and I'll have a look. (and consider accepting this answer if it answers your initial question)